# Location from getLastKnownLocation() is not the same like in Google Map Application. Why?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, locationmanager

I get my current location from `getLastKnownLocation()`

```
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

But when I get the address with `Geocoder` it gives me not the address where I really be.
When I go to the `Google Map Application` it gives me exactly the position where I really be.

**Geocoder:**

```
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 10); 

              for (Address address : addresses) {
                 System.out.println("my location .."+address.getAddressLine(0));

             }
```

So why I can't retrieve with `getLastKnownLocation()` the real current position, but Google can it?

Is there a more accurate method to get my current position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` is not exactly at some time, try again with  `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`

Comment: Great. Would never thought of this. Thanks a lot. Now it's accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Network_provider provides information (Latitudes/Longitudes) based on where the network provider router is Placed. It might possible most of the times that when we access location through network it provides us the nearest possible location of Network router where actually we are present.

Thanks